# Block and/or Silence incoming notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

My company is currently contracted to write a meditation app. While we have the app 90+% done the client has come up with a new requirement they would like implemented. Thankfully we have not agreed to the new requirement as we were not sure if it is possible or not.

They have seen in other apps (games were the only examples they were able to provide) where notifications (i.e. incoming email) did not appear and did not play a sound.

I have searched the old google god and have not been able to come up with an answer for my higher ups. Is there a way to accomplish this or is this something that is only available for games?

Thanks.

Comment: “Only available for games”? You know there’s no OS-level distinction between “games” and “other”, right? :-)

Comment: I didn't believe there were but as I had only seen the functionality there I started to doubt my knowledge.

Comment: You mean incoming notifications belonging to other apps, such as the built-in email app? I've never heard of such a thing, what's a specific example of a game they say can do this?

Comment: I am trying to get a list of examples from them. Right now i am not able to duplicate what they say is possible. I'll let you know when i get examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.  The only thing that I would guess is that you would turn on do not disturb pragmatically.  But there is no code for that, that i know of.